# absolute positioned div with rest of page scrollable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a div at the top of the page that does not move, but I want the rest of the page below that to be scrollable. The scrollbar can only start below the div.

is this possible without using a frame

thanks in advance

Comment: did you tried giving a fixed position to a div?

Comment: `position:fixed;` would do that

Comment: Best this you can do is play with the different position settings. This will greatly improve your understanding of HTML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

html

```
<div id="main">
<div id="header"> Header Content</div>    
<div id="content">
    <ul><li>Hello World!!! </li>
        <li>Hello World!!! </li>
        <li>Hello World!!! </li>
        <li>Hello World!!! </li>
        <li>Hello World!!! </li>           
        </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
      body { margin: 0;}
#main{
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;}
#header
{
position: absolute;
height: 41px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
text-align:center;
display:block;
background: blue;
}
#content
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 41px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y:scroll;               
}


li{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
   padding: 20px; 

}
```

[Demo update](http://jsfiddle.net/d5jf6/3/)

Comment: hi, this gives a horizontal scroll bar, I am looking for the content to be scrollable vertically

Answer (score 1):

Yes u can do it with

```
.some-class {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0
    ...
}
```

Comment: beat me to it, was gonna post the same answer

Comment: hi this sort of works, but the rest of the page can be scrolled over the top of the fixed div.  Is there anyway that the rest of the page starts below this div.

Comment: @Aravind30790 thanks for that but the content cannot be a set size and if I remove the max height of the content then the whole page becomes scrollable

Comment: just set `overflow:auto;` for your content

Comment: @Aravind30790 if I remove the height of the content then the whole page becomes scrollable again http://jsfiddle.net/dc6uq/7/

Comment: @Pavel is there anyway that the scrollbar can start below the topbar?

Comment: im not sure if it is posible with fixed position... i prefer full height scrollbar (imho it looks better) but if u want scrollable just content area use ANonmous Change's absolute position solution.